# What should be the correct definition of a normal space?

Tags: general-topology

When I learned topology from *Munkres'* book of the same name, he defined a topological space $X$ to be normal if

1. One point sets are closed
2. For every pair of disjoint closed sets $A$ and $B$, we have that there exist open sets $U \supseteq A$ and $V \supseteq B$ such that $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

Now consider the countably infinite product of $\Bbb{R}$ with itself, denoted $\Bbb{R}^\omega$ with the product topology. Then a point like

$$(1,1,1,\ldots )$$

cannot possibly be closed because $\Bbb{R}^\omega$ is equipped with the product topology. I believe that if we discard 1) above, $\Bbb{R}^\omega$ will be normal. Thus my question is, is it reasonable to assume that one point sets are closed in the definition of normality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Munkres calls *normal* is what many of us call $T_4$, reserving *normal* for spaces that satisfy (2) but not necessarily (1).

However, you’re mistaken about $\Bbb R^\omega$: every singleton **is** closed. To use your example, if $\langle x_k:k\in\omega\rangle$ is any sequence different from the constant $1$ sequence $s$, there is a $k\in\omega$ such that $x_k\ne 1$. Let $U$ and $V$ be disjoint open intervals about $x_k$ and $1$ in $\Bbb R$; then

$$\left\{y\in\Bbb R^\omega:y_k\in U\right\}\quad\text{and}\quad\left\{y\in\Bbb R^\omega:y_k\in V\right\}$$

are disjoint open nbhds of $x$ and $s$. In particular, the former is an open nbhd of $x$ that does not contain $s$, showing that $x$ is not in $\operatorname{cl}\{s\}$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\operatorname{cl}\{x\}=\{x\}$, i.e., $\{x\}$ is closed.

The property that all singletons are closed is equivalent to the $T_1$ [separation axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom) property and is implied by the $T_2$ (or Hausdorff) property. In normal spaces (meaning those satisfying (2)) $T_1$ implies $T_2$, so some people use the term *normal Hausdorff* for what I call $T_4$ and Munkres calls *normal*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I am little confused because given any sequence $\langle x_k : k \in \omega\rangle$ that differs from $s$, there is no basis element about $\langle x_k \rangle$ that is completely contained in the complement of $\{ s\}$. This is because basis elements in the product topology are of the form $\prod_{k\in \omega} U_k$ where ***all but finitely many*** of the $U_k's$ are equal to $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @BenjaLim: Your assertion is false: $\left\{y\in\Bbb R^\omega:y_k\in U\right\}$ is an open nbhd of $x$ completely contained in the complement of $\{s\}$. The fact that all but one of the factors in this basic open set are $\Bbb R$ is irrelevant: the factor of $U$ for the $k$-th factor ensures that this basic open set does not contain **any** point with a $1$ in the $k$-th coordinate.

Comment: Ah I see where my mistake went. The set that you defined is such that in all but the $k$ - th coordinates we are free to choose entries, whereas at the $k$ - th coordinate the entry must be in $U$. Thanks Brian!

Comment: @BenjaLim: Yes, now you’ve got it. You’re welcome!